# Configure Elastic Search in already existing rest service

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I already have an rest api running on my machine. I wanted to check if I can implement elastic search and Kibana on the application logs so that I can start exploring it

Answer (score 1):

You can install filebeat and stream your logs to elasticsearch.
Depending on the type of logs, you might need to provide an ingest pipeline in elasticsearch to transform your logs as structured documents.